# Can someone provide an xargs example piping mysql query data into another command?

Tags: shell-script, pipe, mysql, xargs

Can someone provide an example for the command `xargs`? I want to do a `mysql` query to return the ID field of a column then feed that result into `xargs` into another command say `mysql` query delete. How can this be done?

Comment: That sounds more like something that you can build up from database commands...

Comment: This is what subselects are good for.. `DELETE FROM (SELECT ...)`.

Comment: There's an example in the `xargs` man page. What are you trying to do? I don't understand what difficulting you're running against. You should at least write down a sample mysql command and its output, and what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xargs deals badly with special chars (" ' space), so I will give you an example using GNU Parallel:

```
sql -n mysql://user:pass@host/my_db "select data from my_table" | parallel -q sql mysql://user:pass@host/my_db "delete from my_table where data='{}'"
```

It takes literally 10 seconds to install GNU Parallel (which includes GNU SQL):

```
wget pi.dk/3 -qO - | sh -x
```

Watch the intro videos to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1